# Laravel eloquent, how can I exclude rows from query when a row meets 2 conditions?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

so I am trying to create a Laravel eloquent query. It is a bit complex, and has a bunch of clauses, all working well, and is querying a single table. But, I want to add a specific condition, described below.

```
->where('date', '>', Carbon::now())
```

This condition works fine, but I want this condition to only apply to specific rows! Assume the condition I want the above where clause to apply to is:

```
->where('row_type', '=', 'someType')
```

Now I don't want to filter for all rows where row_type = 'someType', nor for all rows where date > Carbon::now().

I only want to filter for rows with date > Carbon::now()  WHEN  row_type = 'someType'.

Of course, both 'date' and 'row_type' are columns in my table.

Now to simplify the logic, what I want to do basically is EXCLUDE rows where both (date < Carbon::now() AND row_type = 'someType') are true.

Is this possible to do in a single query in eloquent without inserting raw sql?

I was able to reproduce my query in raw sql:

```
select id, date, row_type from my_table where case when row_type = 'someType' then date > '2019-03-01%' end;
```

Comment: If combinations of `->where()` and `->orWhere()` don't work, maybe some kind of `CASE WHEN ...` would? I'd suggest seeing if you can get the result you want in a manual SQL query (using whatever DB program you use) and then try translating that to eloquent.

Comment: Following edit: Laravel has a `whereRaw()` method, so you can transfer that `case when ... end;` into that and it should work in Eloquent.

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis Will put it in as raw sql if there is no way to do it using the eloquent functions.

Comment: No problem! As far as I know, Laravel doesn't have an out-of-the-box implementation of `CASE WHEN ...`, which is why I suggest the `raw` approach. It might have gotten one recently, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now to simplify the logic, what I want to do basically is EXCLUDE rows where both (date < Carbon::now() AND row_type = 'someType') are true.

Either apply formal Boolean logic `!(A and B) = !A or !B` or just notice that "exclude where both are true" is equivalent to "include if either one is false". So we include those rows where either date is not past (i.e. is future) or the type is not someType.

```php
->where('row_type', '!=', 'someType')->orWhere('date', '>', Carbon::now())
```

If you also have other conditions and including that `orWhere` will screw those up, you should just use nesting for this one:

```php
// ...other wheres...
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('date', '>', Carbon::now())->orWhere('row_type', '!=', 'someType');
})
->where( // ...other wheres...
```

I'll try to walk through SQL to show that this works.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, row_type text, date date);

/* First row is someType and past - it should be excluded */
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(1,'someType', '2019-03-01');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(2,'someType', '2019-03-31');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(3,'otherType', '2019-03-01');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(4,'otherType', '2019-03-01');
COMMIT;
```

The query in op is this:

```sql
SELECT 'Cases from the OP' as '';
SELECT id, row_type, date 
FROM my_table
WHERE
  CASE
    WHEN row_type = 'someType'
      THEN date > '2019-03-22%'
  END;

/* returns */
2|someType|2019-03-31
```

It doesn't even do what you state in words. It also excludes every row where row_type is not someType. This is equivalent to `row_type = 'someType' AND date > '2019-03-22'`. To make it exclude what you stated should be excluded, you have to make it even more complicated:

```sql
SELECT id, row_type, date 
FROM my_table
WHERE
  CASE
    WHEN row_type = 'someType'
      THEN date > '2019-03-22'
    ELSE 1
  END;

/* returns */
2|someType|2019-03-31
3|otherType|2019-03-01
4|otherType|2019-03-01
```

But it would simpler and more appropriate (cases are appropriate when there actually are multiple cases) to just write this:

```sql
SELECT ' ' as '';
SELECT 'The same using OR' as '';
SELECT id, row_type, date
FROM my_table
WHERE
  (row_type != 'someType' OR date > '2019-03-22');

/* returns */
2|someType|2019-03-31
3|otherType|2019-03-01
4|otherType|2019-03-01
```

I wrapped the condition in parentheses as you said you are looking to add other statements as well. And that is what `where(function($q) {$q->...})` would do.

Comment: This doesn't work, because I don't want to exclude all results where row_type = 'someType'.
And if a row is not 'someType' then I don't want the date filter to apply

Comment: @IbrahimChawa that's why it's OR. First `where` includes all rows that are not `someType` and the second applies date filter to remaining (those that are `someType`).  I think you are just approaching your conditions from the wrong end.

Comment: Well, my query is much more complicated than that example. I have a bunch of other where clauses. 
It includes where row_type in (some other types)
and I can't put in a condition like orWhere date > now

Comment: See above comment, I needed a WHERE CASE clause in eloquent, but guess there isn't. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You can do however you like, but I think I can still save you from using a raw statement. See my updated answer.
Any `CASE` statement is replacable with an AND/OR combination. And it is easy and readable for a single-when case. Maybe the nesting of wheres is what you were missing?

Comment: `that's why it's OR. First where includes all rows that are not someType and the second applies date filter to remaining (those that are someType)`.. this is mental gymnastics.. it's not readable _at all_.. a terrible work around in my opinion, i'd rather have a readable raw sql than trying too hard with eloquent

Comment: @abbood I can't agree that a `CASE WHEN` would be easier to understand than `... AND (row_type != some_type OR date > '2019-03-22')`. It's misleading to use cases to check for a single condition. Besides the SQL query in OP doesn't even do what is required, see my updated answer.